# How to use Deep-linking?

Tags: android, deeplink

i am working on Deep-link from an Android application to connect my Android application. Now they are calling my app using below URI

```
kaip.deeplinkSandbox://payment?token=1p51ktwy2qK5sDwNBJy2kP11vK
```

So how to mention this on my app's Manifests file to open my app, when user trying this above from their app.

i want to seperate **schema** , **host** and **path** from the above deeplink data. Please help to finish this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your manifest file inside the  tag. Activity should be your Launcher activity

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="kaip.deeplinkSandbox" />
        </intent-filter>
```

And in your Activity,you can get the link like this:-

```
   Uri data = this.getIntent().getData();
   if (data != null && data.isHierarchical()) {
     String uri = this.getIntent().getDataString();
     Log.i("MyApp", "Deep link clicked " + uri);
   }
```

If any query, you can ask!!

Comment: Thanks @AdeelTurk